# How to handle dependencies in puppet from parent class

Tags: include, parent, puppet, user-defined-types

Main problem: I have some dynamic code in parent class, in subclass I am including additional resource. I want to add the resource to catalog from child before executing parent level.

Could you propose me good dependency command or a tip how to write it another way.

Sample code may be helpful here.

#### Manifest file

```
class class1 {
    file {'C:/Temp/test1':
        content => 'test1',
    }
}

class parent {
    file {'C:/Temp/test2':
        content => template('parent/test2.erb')
    }
}

class parent::child {
    file {'C:/Temp/test3':
        content => 'test3'
    }
}


Class['class1']->Class['parent::child']

include class1
include parent::child
```

#### test2.erb

```
<% scope.catalog.vertices.each do |resource| -%>
  <%= resource -%>
<% end -%>
```

#### Result: test2

```
  Stage[main]  Class[Settings]  Class[main]  Class[Class1]  File[C:/Temp/test1]  Class[Parent]
```

I want it also to include

```
File[C:/Temp/test3]
```

Comment: This is beyond unclear. Can you give an example with an actual use case? The anonymization really makes it hard to follow or get your intent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer, since I didn't get all information for your question.

First I simplify your code, if you think that makes sense, we can start the discussion from it.

#### Manifest file:

```
class class1 {
    file {'C:/Temp/test1':
        content => 'test1',
    }
}
->
class parent {
    file {'C:/Temp/test2':
        content => template('parent/test2.erb')
    }
}

include class1
include parent
```

#### test2.erb

```
<% scope.catalog.vertices.each do |resource| -%>
  <%= resource -%>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Firstly you need a child of 'parent. class. Secondly, your class dependency did not work for me, so i put it below. Finally, at the end i want to include child class.

I have edited your code.

Comment: You need edit your own questions with updates,  such as add new text3 file module. And from your edit, I think you understood where is your problem now.